# PHP Destroy Session on Page Refresh or Exit

Tags: php, session

I am working on a PHP application that allows users to process a payment online. The process is as follows;

- user visits `/index.php` and selects button to 'pay now'
- user is redirected to worldpay and payment is processed
- after successful payment worldpay sends a `success` parameter to my `/callback.php` and this is where I set `$_SESSION[status] = 'success'` before redirecting back to `/index.php`

This all works as expected, if the payment was a success I am able to display a success message, however the message remains even when the user visits other pages of the site and returns to `/index.php`, it also remains if browser tab is closed and re-opened.

In my `/callback.php` file I have;

```
session_start();
// get status sent by worldpay url
$status= $_GET['status'];

if($status=== 'success') {
    $_SESSION['status'] = 'success';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

In my `/index.php` I am checking for the session and displayin the message as below;

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['status']) && ($_SESSION['status'] === 'success') ) {
    echo 'success msg';
}
```

I only need to display the success message once to the user.

How can I destroy `$_SESSION['status']` whenever the user;

- refreshes the page
- leaves the page
- closes tab

Should I be using cookies or some other method?

Comment: From PHP set_cookie expires parameter documentation: "If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes)." Unload event in JS when leaving the page. And..call set_cookie() each time the page is refreshed/loaded to destroy the previous session cookie?

Comment: Why not `unset` the `$_SESSION` when displaying the `"success msg"` with `unset($_SESSION['status'])`?

Comment: @akaBase I like this idea, thanks! Does this mean that if the `success msg` is displayed then the user immediately goes through the same payment process, they would see a new `success message`? Or would the  `$_SESSION['status']` be destroyed completely?

Comment: It is destroyed if unset. So if the user repeats the payment process nothing about the old $_SESSION['status'] will be shown,

Comment: Sorry bit late but as  @TorbjörnStabo said they would see a new payment process with the newly created session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can unset the $_SESSION['status'] after displaying the success message ONCE.

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['status']) && ($_SESSION['status'] === 'success') ) {
   echo 'success msg';
   unset($_SESSION['status']);
}
```